# Fluid Obstacle while animated by modifier

Tags: modifiers, physics, fcurves

I'm new to 3D animation, and was trying out Blender. I've come across an issue that I'm not sure how to fix.

I wanted to try throwing fluid onto a subdivided plane, whose vertex's are being moved by the modifier 'displace'. The strength of displacement is being modulated by an audio file I put in through "bake sound to audio file".

The problem I'm facing is getting the fluid to interact with the displaced plane. I can't apply the displacement because that unhooks the f-curve and it stops being animated. Does anyone know a method (even if I have to start from scratch) that would allow me to make this interaction possible?

Comment: From experience, animated obstacles (whether the mesh is actually animated as in your case or even just moving/rotating within the fluid domain) do not work correctly - the fluid can result in being repelled through or away from the obstacle and effectively ‘disappears’ from the domain - it is not a physically accurate simulation. I believe there are fluid sim developments in the pipeline (mantaflow?) or possibly you could try flipfluids (paid for addon?).